# AIF service over https

Tags: wcf-binding, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, aif

I just deployed AIF service (Activated) over the net.tcp, it is providing WSDL URI at the same time, how can I use https binding to consume AIF.

And Whats the way to configure the URL in the web.config of a .net from where I am consuming AIF service.

I tried to change the url explicitly to Https protocol by the below line

```
client.Endpoint.Address = new ...
```

but the exception is coming and says, it is configured for net.tcp not via http.

Please share any of the snippet for changing the net.tcp configuration to https from AX 2012 and where I am consuming, how can I configure the URL in the web.config.

Comment: I doubt it's possible. You'll have to configure a new inbound port via the HTTP adapter.

Comment: Agreed with Sir Troll, you should deploy unsing the HTTP adapter if you want http binding.